# c++: mutex, guards and function calls

Tags: c++, concurrency, scope, locking, mutex

I was wondering. When I use a `std::mutex _lock` and want to rely on guards to release it, can I use it like this?

```
class MyClass{
private:
    mutable std::mutex _lock;
    void subroutine(){/*...*/}
public:
    void foo(){
        std::lock(_lock);std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(_lock, std::adopt_lock);
        subroutine();
        //require I still have the lock here
        //...
        return; //g goes out of scope ==> _lock is released
    }
};
```

Or would the call to `subroutine` already cause the lock to be released? If the latter turns out to be the case, what are my options?

**Update**

What about this case?

```
class MyClass{
private:
    mutable std::mutex _lock;
public:
    void subroutine(){ //can be called on its own
        std::lock(_lock);std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(_lock, std::adopt_lock);
        /*...*/
    }
    void foo(){
        std::lock(_lock);std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(_lock, std::adopt_lock);
        subroutine();
        //require I still have the lock here
        //...
        return; //g goes out of scope ==> _lock is released
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to subroutine would not cause the lock to be released.
The thread's lock on _lock is released when the std::lock_guard object goes out of scope (as you mention in your comment).

```
void foo(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{_lock}; // lock the mutex
    subroutine(); // lock is held here during this call
    // so subroutine must not attempt to lock the mutex _lock!
    return; // lg goes out of scope => its destructor is called which releases the lock on _lock
}
```

To answer your second question, you have a problem when foo acquires a lock on _lock and then calls subroutine, which again tries to lock _lock. A thread cannot acquire a lock on a mutex on which it already holds a lock. I would re-think your class design. If you absolutely must have this design you could do something like

```
void subroutine(bool called_from_foo = false)
{
    if(!called_from_foo)
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{_lock};
    /* ... */
}

void foo()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{_lock};
    subroutine(true);
    /* ... */
    return;
}
```

Although **I would not recommend this** because it would be easy to use subroutine in a wrong way, causing undefined behavior in your program.

If you find yourself having to pass the owner of a lock between functions I would take a look at std::unique_lock, because this type is moveable.

Comment: Does that change if ``subroutine`` is public and also executes ``std::lock(_lock);std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(_lock, std::adopt_lock);``? (see edit above)

Comment: I'm a at a bit of a loss why anyone would code like that.  What it appears to do is to attempt to lock the mutex again - which will either result in an error or a deadlock unless `_lock` is a `recursive_mutex`. 
Using a recursive mutex in this way has a really bad code-smell to it.  You probably want to look at your class design.